# Can a NG player be summoned by a NG+ player (and vice versa)?

Tags: dark-souls

Can a NG player be summoned by a NG+ player (and vice versa) ?

I'm curious as I'm going to start my NG+ with my lvl 61 sorceror. Maybe lvl 61 is too low for NG+, from what I've read people seem to be lvl 150 by the time they beat Gwyn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the levels matter for summoning (I think it's +/- 10%). You can interact with players in co op/invasion that are not in the same play through as you. You can be in NG and they in NG+, or vise versa with no problem.

Comment: Has this been confirmed? It would mean that you can be summoned into an easier or harder game.

Comment: Yea. If you are in NG and get summoned to an NG+ game you will notice the enemies are harder to kill, give more souls, etc.